# Authorize attribute is ignoring [AllowAnonymous]

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, authorization, custom-attributes

I have set-up a customer Authorization Attribute in my asp.net web api

global file:

```
  FilterConfig.RegisterHttpFilters(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters);
```

FilterConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterHttpFilters(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new TokenAuthentication(""));
    }
```

Authentication Class:

```
  public class TokenAuthentication : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    private readonly string realm;

    public bool AllowMultiple { get { return false; } }

    public TokenAuthentication(string realm)
    {
        this.realm = "realm=" + realm;
    }      

    public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var request = context.Request;

        // Receive token from the client. Here is the example when token is in header:
        string token = null;

        if (request.Headers.Contains("Token"))
        {
            token = request.Headers.GetValues("Token").FirstOrDefault();
        }

        if (token != null && token != "")
        {
            // Get your secret key from the configuration
            var secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JWTSecurityKey"];

            try
            {
                //Get the Payload from the token
                string jsonPayload = JWT.JsonWebToken.Decode(token, secretKey);

                int separatorIndex = jsonPayload.IndexOf(';');
                string userId = "";
                DateTime timeIssued = DateTime.MinValue;
                if (separatorIndex >= 0)
                {
                    //userId = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(jsonPayload.Substring(0, separatorIndex)));
                    userId = jsonPayload.Substring(1, separatorIndex - 1);
                    string tmpTime = jsonPayload.Substring(separatorIndex + 1, (jsonPayload.Length - separatorIndex) - 2);
                    timeIssued = DateTime.Parse(tmpTime);
                }

                short TokenTTL = 10;                //minuets
                //Int16.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenTTL"],TokenTTL);               

                // if ((DateTime.Now.Subtract(timeIssued).TotalMinutes >= TokenTTL))
                if ((DateTime.Now.Subtract(timeIssued).TotalMinutes < 0))
                {
                    context.ErrorResult = new UnauthorizedResult(new AuthenticationHeaderValue[0], context.Request);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Save user in context                
                    var claims = new List<Claim>()
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userId)
                    };
                    var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Basic");
                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[] { id });

                    // Set the user name to the user id in the httpcontext which is passed to the controller
                    context.Principal = principal;
                }

            }
            catch (JWT.SignatureVerificationException)
            {
                context.ErrorResult = new UnauthorizedResult(new AuthenticationHeaderValue[0], context.Request);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        context.Result = new ResultWithChallenge(context.Result, realm);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public class ResultWithChallenge : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly IHttpActionResult next;
    private readonly string realm;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="next"></param>
    /// <param name="realm"></param>
    public ResultWithChallenge(IHttpActionResult next, string realm)
    {
        this.next = next;
        this.realm = realm;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var res = await next.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
        if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            res.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Add(
               new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", this.realm));
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Now my issue is this class is being called even when the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute is applied to my Controllers Action.

This is giving me trouble specifically with the login action as the user does not have a token yet.

How can I rectify this?

Comment: You must check inside the custom attribute if the resource controller / action has the  [AllowAnonymous].

Comment: @Fals any Suggestions as how to do that? Is that information included in the context?

Answer (score 5):

`AllowAnonymous` will work only with authorization filter. What you have here is an authentication filter. Use `OverrideAuthentication` from System.Web.Http instead.

UPDATE

Where in my original answer did I say you must implement authentication? All I have said is, if you do not want the `AuthenticateAsync` method of the `TokenAuthentication` to be called, apply `OverrideAuthentication`, instead of `AllowAnonymous`. `AllowAnonymous` will work only with authroization filters and not authentication filters. So, in your `Login` action, you will need to have `OverrideAuthentication` applied like this.

```
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    [OverrideAuthentication]
    public HttpResponeMessage Login(Dto dto)
    { }
}
```

Comment: Im confused, You said I have an Authentication Filter, but I must implement the Authentication? Have I not done that? Could you elaborate?